# How to filter queryset on the LearnerQuestionAnswer Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model named Quiz. Each Quiz has a set of related questions in the model Quiz_Question.

Quiz Model:-

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    quiz_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Quiz_Question Model:-

```
class Quiz_Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, related_name='questions')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now I can get all the questions for a particular quiz using the related_name attribute as follows:-

```
all_quizes = Quiz.objects.all()
```

A particular quiz:-

```
quiz = all_quizes[0]
```

All the questions related to this quiz as follows:-

```
all_related_questions = quiz.questions.all()
```

I have another model as a LearnerQuestionAnswer where learner is a normal django user:-

```
class LearnerQuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    quiz_question = models.ForeignKey(Quiz_Question)
    learner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I can filter out the quiz and learner specific questions on the Quiz_Question Model like this:-

```
quiz = all_quizes[0]
learner= User.objects.get(id=1)
Quiz_Question.objects.filter(quiz=quiz, learnerquestionanswer__learner=learner)
```

How can I filter out similarly on the LearnerQuestionAnswer Model so that I can get quiz and learner specific queryset just like the above one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `quiz_question__quiz` lookup to filter by quize. Use following query to query by quiz and learner:

```
quiz = all_quizes[0]
learner= User.objects.get(id=1)
LearnerQuestionAnswer.objects.filter(quiz_question__quiz=quiz, learner=learner)
```

Check [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) of the doc about filter by related model's fields.